# The effect of fullering on the rate of blood loss from puncture wounds

Tags: humans, weapons

The grooves found along the sides of many bladed weapons, known as [fullering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuller_(weapon)), are intended to lighten and strengthen the blade.

However, they are also colloquially known as 'blood gutters', though this does not reflect their primary purpose.

Let us assume that we have two weapons that are identical other than the presence or absence of fullering: double-edged daggers with blades 30cm long from tip to hilt, and 5 cm wide and 1 cm thick at the hilt with a triangular profile.  One of the two weapons is unfullered, the other has been fullered on each side of the blade with two triangular grooves beginning at 5mm in width and 3mm in depth, that run from the hilt to points 75% of the way along the  length of the blade.

Let us further suppose that we were to stab hypothetical twin human victims of average human height and mass (without respect to gender) with these blades in an identical manner, the blades penetrating directly and without any lateral broadening of the wound tract by twisting motions of the blade 25cm into the torso from behind and into the middle of a highly vascular organ such as one of the kidneys, such that the only difference between the victims was the presence or absence of the fullering of the blade.

The victims can be assumed to be in identical, comfortable, indoor environments, neither hot nor cold, and for as long as they can remain conscious with these injuries, remain relatively still after being injured.

The questions:

- If the blades were to be left in the wounds after they were inflicted and not removed afterwards, what (if any) difference would the presence or absence of fullering make to the rate of blood loss?
- What rates of blood loss could we expect if the weapons were not removed for some time?
- If the weapons were to be removed, either immediately or after some time, how would this affect the rate of blood loss, and how long could the victims be expected to survive in the following cases, assuming that neither medical attention nor first aid of any sort will be available for 24 hours after the injury is inflicted, and that withdrawing the weapon causes no further injury?:

  1. Stabbed with an unfullered weapon that remains in the wound for 15 minutes.
  2. Stabbed with a fullered weapon that remains in the wound for 15 minutes.
  3. Stabbed with an unfullered weapon that is then withdrawn after 30 seconds.
  4. Stabbed with an fullered weapon that is then withdrawn after 30 seconds.

Does the presence of fullering on a blade justify their being referred to as 'blood gutters'?

Comment: I have to agree with the close vote on this. While asking for help designing a weapon to meet the purpose you have in mind would definitely be on topic (we've done it before, after all), asking what impact on biology a particular existing weapon has lacks any constructive component, so making it not about world _building_.

Answer (score 3):

**The presence of the fuller on a blade does not make any difference with regard to blood loss, whether the blade is in the wound or not.**

The human skin has a somewhat elastic property as a self-defense; when the human skin is punctured, the skin closes tightly around the object and closes again if the object is removed.

Don't forget that the fuller also doesn't affect the size/thickness of the wound, since it's in the middle of the blade and doesn't extend out to the tip. In fact, if you look at a blade from the tip towards the hilt, you often can't even see the fuller - this means that when the blade enters, whether or not the blade has a fuller makes no difference to the size of the wound. Assuming you stabbed the same spot on 2 identical humans with identical weapons (minus the fuller on one of them), after pulling out the weapons the wound would look identical.

Pulling out the weapon resulting in more blood loss is also often misinterpreted. Whether or not you pull out the weapon, the victim is still bleeding. If you pull out the weapon, the blood will likely flow out of the wound, but as long as you keep the weapon in the wound, it applies a bit of pressure to the wounded area, and helps to keep more of the blood in the human body. However, you're **still bleeding inside** - if you leave the wound untreated, you're still going to die.

So no, the presence of fullering does not justify the "blood gutter" name.